# How to save aUIImage using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

How do I save an Image to User Defaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it as NSData.
To get a NSData object from a UIImage, you can use one of the following functions:

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (UIImage *image);
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (UIImage *image);
```

And to turn the NSData back into an image, you can use imageWithData or initWithData

```
UIImage * a = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
UIImage * b = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

But maybe it's a better idea to write it to a different file.

Comment: Well then how do I write ti to the temp folder and if I want to overwrite then how do I do that, also how do I read that file back?
Thank you for the code btw.

Comment: You can save the NSData with one of the writeToFile methods

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.png"];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Comment: Thank you so mush this helps my get what I wanted

Comment: how to read this file after that? how to check was file successful saved?

Comment: Guys.. Ever heard of something called "documentation"? It may help to have a look at it...